# Securely identifying a user

Tags: javascript, node.js, local-storage, steam, steamworks-api

I am building a trading website for the game CS:GO, currently when a user logs-in to the site for the first time using their steam account, I assign them a unique 20 character long string as an ID. This ID is sent to the server (NodeJS) every time they make a request to verify all the information they are sending is valid, such as the items in their inventory, their user name and profile picture etc. However as this unique ID is stored in their local storage and then sent to the server, if they get hold of another users ID they would be able to access his account on the site and therefore have the ability to steal their items. What would be a better approach to identifying users that would be more secure?

Comment: You could have them login every http request :p Jokes aside, the most common way is still to use a session cookie. And yes, these can be stolen but you have to make sure to set the cookie properties correctly (httpOnly+secure, depending on your needs). In any case I'd increase the session id to 256 chars or more. Also you could have serverside protections like IP recognition (this is another story again since mobile users might have a change of IP more easily)

Comment: You should never trust user input therefore you cannot trust users to send the correct steam user id. After login with steam you receive a token which u can use to retrieve this users steam id and other information. So on client you login and send the token to your server to login or register the user. When a user authenticates using a steam token you then set a session like you would normally do. But its important to reference users by steam id so you can be sure your handling the correct user. https://partner.steamgames.com/doc/webapi_overview/oauth

Comment: I've added some middleware that checks if the user is authenticated before sending any sort of request using their session.id that steam assigns. If they change their session.id they are logged out. Does this sound like the right approach?

Comment: I'd suggest looking up some authentication mechanisms, there are probably some existing js libraries out there that manage it for you. And yes one way or another it is going to work with some sort of "session id", may that be nested inside a JWT or just as a cookie. Losing either of them to an attacker is bad

Answer (score 1):

You should issue them a Json Web Token : https://jwt.io/introduction
Then they send the JWT in the request headers and you can validate that this token corresponds to the user you issued it for on your backend

Answer (score 0):

You should not store any ID or tokens in the browser ,instead only use session cookies with the backend, that is the only proven secure approach. Assuming you use the SameSite (strict or lax), Secure and HttpOnly cookies attributes.

if you need to use JWT tokens, then consider using the BFF pattern as mentioned in these videos:

- [alert‘OAuth 2 0’; // The impact of XSS on OAuth 2 0 in SPAs](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lEnbi4KClVw&t=2618s)
- [Securing SPAs and Blazor Applications using the BFF (Backend for Frontend) Pattern - Dominick Baier](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xzRhabmlc8M)